# What qualifies as a demon?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer, demons

In Buffy, you see hundreds of things referred to as "demons" or "demonic", and many other things (Trolls, Werewolves, Witches, etc) are not. But what actually counts as a demon in the Buffyverse?

Comment: Basically anything that's not a god, a robot or a human.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_(Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer)

Comment: This immediately made me think of Robert Asprin's *Myth Adventures* books. There, "demon" is a bastardization of "*dimen*sional traveler". The Buffyverse rules don't seem too far off this....

Answer (score 4):

Typically, anything from another dimension that isn't powerful enough to be called a god.  Also, good looking extra-dimensional beings are sometimes not called demons.

A human who has been in another dimension and been altered has been called a demon, I believe.

Remember that Anya was/is a demon.

Comment: +1.  Additionally, they seem to refer to all *known* alternate dimensions (with the notable exception of Heaven) as "Hell Dimensions," even when they have relatively little information about what the dimension actually is.

Comment: Not the world of shrimp.

Answer (score 2):

The term demon is specifically defined in the [Buffy the Vampire Slayer Encyclopedia: The Ultimate Guide to the Buffyverse](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33783445-buffy-the-vampire-slayer-encyclopedia).

> **Demon:**
>
> ***Supernatural beings native to hell dimensions.*** Generally they lack souls and are considered evil. They often possess great strength and
>   endurance, as well as powers like teleportation or psychokinesis

It follows that anything that doesn't fall into this category is some sort of hybrid or simply mis-described.